# How to transfer an immutable part of a function to other projects

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-class

In the `print_foo` function, there is a part of the code that changes from project to project.
And there is a part of the code which is always the same. It is responsible for working with the `Counter` class.

What's the best way to change the code to just move the unchanged part of the function from project to project?

Is it possible to implement this through the decorator? If so, how can the decorator query the attributes of an object, in this case `foobar`. And how would it save them to an object of the `Counter` class?

```py
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 0
        self.status = 'Off'

    def counter_foo(self, n):
        self.foo += n

    def set_status(self, status):
        self.status = status


class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = Counter()
        self.status = 'On'

    def print_foo(self, n=1):
        # This part is changing in every project
        print('foo' * n)

        # This part doesn't change. And this part I want take out separately
        self.counter.counter_foo(n)
        if self.status == 'On':
            self.counter.set_status(self.status)


def main():
    foobar = First()
    foobar.print_foo(8)
```

I want in the `First`, just write the function

```
def print_foo(self, n=1):
        print('foo' * n)
```

But with the preservation of the functionality of this part

```
self.counter.counter_foo(n)
        if self.status == 'On':
            self.counter.set_status(self.status)
```

In a real project, it is 6 functions and tens of lines. I can't copy them every time by hand.

Comment: Since you're using `class Foo(object):`, do you need solution that's compatible with Python 2?

Comment: No. I work with Python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a decorator as follows and still use it for your scope since the self name is just a name at the end...

```
from functools import wraps

def increment_counter(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.counter.counter_foo(n)
        if self.status == 'On':
           self.counter.set_status(self.status)
        return result
    return wrapper_func
```

You can then decorate print_foo with it as:

```
class First:
  @increment_counter
  def print_foo(self, n=1):
    # This part is changing in every project
    print('foo' * n)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Thank you.
But what if in the `First`, I need to decorate several functions, but they all have to work with one `Counter` object?

Comment: Are the functions all members of the same class, i. e. First?

Comment: Yes. They're all in the same class.

Comment: Then yes, you can decorate them all with the same decorator and it would access always the same `Counter` object instance through the `self` argument.